# comparing multiple array and sorting them fast php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

so I'm making this web app where I need to fetch data from multiple social network websites and sort them according to the posts creation date and time I need to merge all the feeds into a single array and show them later...

so this is I have done so far:

> ->data fetch from twitter, facebook, instagram
>
> ->3 different array's containing all data.

now I need to figure out a way to sort them and merge them in a single array....

wrote this function but it takes time:

```
function sortNjoin($arr1, $arr2)
{
    $length = count($arr1);
    $sortedArray = array();
    if(count($arr1)>count($arr2))
    {
        $length = count($arr2);
    }

    $date1 ='';
    $date2 = '';
    for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++)
    {
        for($j=0;$j<$length;$j++)
        {
            switch($arr1['type'])
            {
                case 'f':
                    $date1 = date_parse($arr1['dataInfo'][$i]['updated_time']);
                    break;
                case 't':
                    $date1 = date_parse($arr1['dataInfo'][$i]['created_at']);
                    break;
                case 'i':
                    $date1 = date_parse($arr1['dataInfo'][$i]['external_created_at']);
                    break;
            }
            switch($arr2['type'])
            {
                case 'f':
                    $date2 = date_parse($arr2['dataInfo'][$j]['updated_time']);
                    break;
                case 't':
                    $date2 = date_parse($arr2['dataInfo'][$j]['created_at']);
                    break;
                case 'i':
                    $date2 = date_parse($arr2['dataInfo'][$j]['external_created_at']);
                    break;
            }
            $date_string1 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime($date1['hour'], $date1['minute'], $date1['second'], $date1['month'], $date1['day'], $date1['year']));
            $date_string2 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime($date2['hour'], $date2['minute'], $date2['second'], $date2['month'], $date2['day'], $date2['year']));

            if($date_string1 >= $date_string2)
            {
                $sortedArray[$i]['dataInfo'] = $arr1['dataInfo'][$i];
                $sortedArray[$i]['type'] = $arr1['type'];
            }
            else
            {
                $sortedArray[$i]['dataInfo'] = $arr2['dataInfo'][$j];
                $sortedArray[$i]['type'] = $arr2['type'];
            }
        }
    }

    return $sortedArray;

}
```

Comment: How big are these arrays?

Comment: each array is of around 50 count and each count has another 10-20 fields....

Comment: We don't have a great [mcve] here.  Is this a merging question or a sorting question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UDPATE**
NOTE: I've user `Facebook` & `Twitter` data

**Function to sort in descending order by value**

```
function sortArr($a, $b){
    return $b['date'] - $a['date'];
}
```

**Code Here**

```
<?php
    //json to associative array
    $fb = json_decode(@'{"data": [{
                                 "id": "X999_Y999",
                                 "from": {
                                         "name": "Tom Brady", "id": "X12"
                                         },
                                  "message": "Looking forward to 2010!",
                                  "created_time": "2010-08-02T21:27:44+0000",
                                   "updated_time": "2010-08-02T21:27:44+0000"
                               }]}',true);
//twitter json

   $twitter = json_decode(@'{"results":[{
                                        "text":"@twitterapi  tinyurl.com/ctrefg",
                                         "from_user":"jkoum",
                                         "id":1478555574,
                                         "from_user_id":1833773,
                                         "created_at":"Wed, 08 Apr 2009 19:22:10 +0000"}]

                                        }',true);

//Rename Array's key to common key name
     $fb = array_map(function($fb) {
           return array(
                'id' => $fb['id'],
                'from' => $fb['from'],
                'message' => $fb['message'],
                'date' => $fb['updated_time']
           );
        }, $fb);

     $twitter = array_map(function($twitter {
           return array(
                'id' => $twitter ['id'],
                'from' => $twitter ['from_user'],
                'message' => $twitter ['text'],
                'date' => $fbtwitter 'updated_time']
           );
        }, $twitter );
     //Now Both Array has same key i.e id,from,message,date and we can merged them
      $mergedArr=array_merge($fb,$twitter);

     //Now sort the merge array by value of ['date'] and we get the result
     usort($mergedArr,"sortArr") // sortArr = function we've written above.
     print_r($mergedArr);
 ?>
```

NOTE: I've selected only few data from both JSON to reduce the space.

!!I hope this helps You!!

Comment: Their are more data also other then date and time see sample:

Comment: Ok. point noted. But it's hard without seeing the real structure of the array

Comment: array(55) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    ["created_at"]=>
      string(30) "Wed Aug 03 08:35:36 +0000 2016"
    ["message"]=>
    string(343) "some text here for description"
    ["permalink_url"]=>
    string(118) "https://www.facebook.com/the.travel/photos/a.469779516322.1073741828.45399142761337/5914456752688/?type=3"
    ["id"]=>
    string(31) "453991124761437_591724567672688"
    ["from"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(17) "The Travel"
      ["id"]=>
      string(15) "453991414761637"
    }
    ["name"]=>
    string(15) "Timeline Photos"
  }

Comment: I don't see the `date` with which you wanted to sort the array. Can you include that too

Comment: see "created_at" field fetching that i use the date_parse and then date to create a date to compare in php

Comment: but I see 2 different dates `created_at` & `external_created_date`

Comment: ya so the data is from 3 social networks "facebook for f", "instagram for i","twitter for t" and every social network api uses different field name to show creating time so i gotta write it in a switch case and then parse date and compare it.....

Comment: Thanks for the help it really worked, but now its takes atleast 8 seconds to process data....but i'll of something...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$foo = array(
    array(
        'title' => 'Foo One',
        'date_info' => array(
            'created_at' => '2006-12-12 10:00:30'
        ) 
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Foo Two',
        'date_info' => array(
            'created_at' => '2006-12-12 10:23:00'
        ) 
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Foo Three',
        'date_info' => array(
            'created_at' => '2006-12-12 10:47:00'
        ) 
    )
);
$bar = array(
    array(
        'title' => 'Bar One',
        'date_info' => array(
            'created_at' => '2006-12-12 10:00:00'
        ) 
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Bar Two',
        'date_info' => array(
            'created_at' => '2006-12-12 10:13:00'
        ) 
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Bar Three',
        'date_info' => array(
            'created_at' => '2006-12-12 10:47:30'
        ) 
    )
);


$all = array_merge($foo, $bar);
usort($all,
    function($a, $b) {
        $ts_a = strtotime($a['date_info']['created_at']);
        $ts_b = strtotime($b['date_info']['created_at']);

        return $ts_a > $ts_b;
    }
);
var_export($all);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'title' => 'Bar One',
    'date_info' => 
    array (
      'created_at' => '2006-12-12 10:00:00',
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'title' => 'Foo One',
    'date_info' => 
    array (
      'created_at' => '2006-12-12 10:00:30',
    ),
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'title' => 'Bar Two',
    'date_info' => 
    array (
      'created_at' => '2006-12-12 10:13:00',
    ),
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'title' => 'Foo Two',
    'date_info' => 
    array (
      'created_at' => '2006-12-12 10:23:00',
    ),
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'title' => 'Foo Three',
    'date_info' => 
    array (
      'created_at' => '2006-12-12 10:47:00',
    ),
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'title' => 'Bar Three',
    'date_info' => 
    array (
      'created_at' => '2006-12-12 10:47:30',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php). This allows you to sort an array using a user-defined function.

Comment: I know you are 4 points short, but this is really just a comment. This type of  answer attracts downvotes ___I did not DV___ and if that happens you will loose rep points and take longer to get to 50 reps. Until you have 50 reps stick to questions that are well asked and therefore easily answered without needing clarification

Comment: Will do @RiggsFolly! Thanks for not downvoting me.